# Two switches what is it for and what does it mean?

Tags: electrical, switch

I am not expertise as an Electrician here but I wanted to ask anyone here why do I have two switches here and what does that mean ?[image]

Can anyone point me a good website that can I read about it ? I recently put up ceiling fan and had have no clue why I have two and we have them in several rooms.

Comment: Probably one for the light and one for the fan.

Comment: What do the switches *control*?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the kind of place a person might ordinarily put a ceiling fan... And if they also fit a ceiling fan-rated box when they built the place... Then most likely they also put the extra apparatus to allow you to switch the ceiling fan and light separately.

That would be /3 (or /4) cable in the walls and  a 2-gang switch box for 2 normal switches (so you don't have to use those janky twin switches and *can* use bulky dimmer, fan speed control or smart switch modules.) And my guess is they gave you two plain switches by default.

That's fairly standard for new builds, they want to let you pick your own fan or chandelier.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Harper is probably right. The one nearest the door is usually for the main light and the one furthest from the door is almost always for the fan. It could be for a second set of lights in the room, but that would have been obvious, unless it is a light in the closet.

If the two switch legs from the switches go up to the ceiling fan box, when you put the fan up, there should have been two dark-colored wires in the box. With newer wire they would probably be black and red. You could have connected them separately: one to the fan and the other to the light kit on the fan. However, if you were used to only having one switch you might not have noticed the other wire or simply used the one that had been connected to the previous light and connected both the fan and the light to only one switch leg. This is my best guess at what happened, since I can't see what the wiring looks like.

Your ceiling fan probably had a black wire for the fan and a blue wire for its light kit. If you tied them both to only one of the wires, you would only get a reaction when one of the switches is on, and both fan and light should come on together. The other switch would do nothing. On the other hand, if you tied them all four together (the black and blue from the fan and the black and red from the ceiling box), either switch would turn on both the fan and the light, and you would have to turn both switches to off to turn both off. I don't think that's what you did because you probably would have mentioned the peculiarity.

To make use of your other switch, if they are indeed for the fan and the light, you should separate the fan's black and blue wires, put them each on their own separate switch leg.

You can learn about this at: https://laokoonlamp.com/how-to-wire-ceiling-fan-and-light-separately/ or just search for "wiring a fan and light."